# Initializing Array of Structure in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

I have the following structure

```
typedef struct {
    int buf[BUF_SIZE]; // the buffer
    size_t len; // number of items in the buffer
    pthread_mutex_t mutex; // needed to add/remove data from the buffer
    pthread_cond_t can_produce; // signaled when items are removed
    pthread_cond_t can_consume; // signaled when items are added
};
```

Initially I was simply initializing it as follows

```
buffer_t buffer = {
    .len = 0,
    .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    .can_produce = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,
    .can_consume = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
};
```

Although I would like to initialize an array of buffer_t with those values, although I'm not quite sure how to properly do it.

Something like

```
buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY] = {
    .len = 0,
    .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
    .can_produce = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,
    .can_consume = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
};
```

(Which I realize is incorrect)

Edit: I ended up using

```
buffer_t buffers[NUM_THREADS];

for (i = 0, i < 3, i ++) {
       buffers[i] = (buffer_t) {
                .len = 0,
                .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
                .can_produce = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER,
                .can_consume = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
            };  
}
```

Comment: Loop over each buffer in the array... Initialise it as before... Profit?

Comment: @belgin Fish, Did the loop solution suggested here actually work for you? I don't think it will work.

Comment: It compiled, I haven't gotten to the point of actually using the buffer yet. I've updated my answer with the solution I ended up using, can you give me your input on it? @BlueMoon

Comment: @BelginFish OK. I see your update. Actually, that's undefined. You can't cast a static mutex/cv like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `NUM_ARRAY` isn't too big, you can do something like this:

```
#define NUM_ARRAY 3

buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY] = {
    { {0}, 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER},
    { {0}, 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER},
    { {0}, 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER}
};
```

Or you could explicitly code it like this:

```
buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY];
int i;
for (i=0; i<NUM_ARRAY; i++) {
    memset(buffer[i].buf, 0, sizeof(buffer[i].buf));
    buffer[i].len = 0;
    buffer[i].mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    buffer[i].can_produce = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
    buffer[i].can_consume = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
}
```

EDIT:

So it looks like the `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` and `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER` macros can't be used in an assignment like this as it's meant to be used only in initializations and contains `{` and `}` characters.

So you need to use initialization syntax as others have suggested:

```
buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY];
int i;
for (i=0; i<NUM_ARRAY; i++) {
    buffer[i] = (buffer_t) {
        0, 0, PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER
    };
}
```

Comment: I had tried something similar to this earlier and even using your code example I receiving "expected expression before { token" for the final 3 initializations in the for loop, do you have any idea why?

Comment: You need a `{}` pair to initialize each array and each struct, and there needs to be a comma between each array element / struct field.  You probably had a mismatch somewhere.

Comment: Why not use a compound literal and avoid `memset`?

Comment: @Olaf I'm not familiar with compound literals, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: The loop solution won't work. Satic initialization is not allowed by POSIX anywhere other than at initialization (even if it compiles).

Comment: @BlueMoon what do you propose I do then?

Comment: @BelginFish I suggest either you use the option 1 in this answer (type *everything*). Or use `pthread_mutex_init()` and `pthread_cond_init()` in a loop. The "EDIT" solution is UB.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the curly braces to initialize the array, so your last example is incorrect indeed.

There are multiple ways to initialize the whole array with the same `struct` every time:

1. Initialize each array member explicitly. Example:

   ```
   buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY] = {
       {
           .len = 0,
           .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
           ...
       },
       {
           .len = 0,
           .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
       },
       ...
   };
   ```

   This is pretty tedious, though. A standardese way would be to...
2. Use a `for` loop:

   ```
   buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY];
   for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ARRAY; ++i) {
       buffer[i] = (buffer_t) {
           .len = 0,
           .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
           ...
       };
   }
   ```

   **Way** better<sup>1</sup>. However, there's still...
3. [Designated initializer lists](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html). Some of them have been standardized like ones you are using but this one hasn't. Therefore it's a non-standard GCC extension but worth to mention anyway. Example:

   ```
   buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY] = {
       [0 ... (NUM_ARRAY - 1)] = {
           .len = 0,
           .mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
           ...
       }
   };
   ```

**I recommend the 2<sup>nd</sup> option, though.**

---

<sup>1</sup> The `(buffer_t) { }` syntax is available only since C99. If your compiler doesn't support it, use simple assignment per `struct` member.

Comment: Options 2 & 3 invoke UB.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Can you elaborate why? It is correct by the standard. And the uppercase macros should yield a constant expression. For the latter even a non-constant expression would be allowed, as it uses a gcc extension anyway.

Comment: @Olaf See my comment in the other answer. The same is applicable to compound literals too. Though, I am not completely sure about option 3 since I don't know how the range initialization works.

Comment: @BlueMoon Yeah, thing is... I don't understand the comment. ^^ Where is static initialization involved?

Comment: @BlueMoon: Only case 1 uses static initialisation and only if at file- scope or `static buffer_t`.

Comment: @Olaf I am not talking about "static initialization" as in the "static" keyword or similar. An initialization of a mutex or conditional variable has two ways. (1) static initialization (2) using the init function (see my comment in other answer). The compound literal way is *not* equivalent to (1) and hence option 2 of this answer is UB. I don't know how gcc implements the range based initialization. So I am not sure about 3.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Well, presuming the macros **are** guaranteed _constant expressions_, they are very well equivalent with respect to the given fields (other fields will be nulled). For gcc, they can also be non-constant as an extension. Your comments remain unclear. Maybe you provide an answer yourself and elaborate.

Comment: @BlueMoon: And for case 3: That would be functionally identical to case 2 or use a large initialiser.

Comment: @Olaf "macros are guaranteed constant expressions" -- not true. POSIX doesn't mandate that for PTHREAD_MUTEXT_INITIALIZER and others. Usually, PTHREAD_MUTEXT_INITIALIZER etc is of the form `{ {...}, {..} ..}`. So obviously, that can't be used anywhere other than initialization. My last comment in the other answer is my answer, nothing more to add really.

Comment: @BlueMoon Ah, so it's only about `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`?

Comment: @cad Yes and `PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER` too.

Comment: @BlueMoon: Well, with _constant expression_ I meant something which consists of only constant expressions, i.e. suitable for an initialiser. As I understand now, this is true for the macros here, so I still do not see an issue. (And if not, the compiler would signal an error; gcc would accept the variable expression, but that would also work).

Answer (score 0):

If your buffer is global, you can leave the initialization in this special case, because PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER is a structure with all zeroes. Otherwise, you would have no other choice than to initialize all members or loop over it programmatically.

Comment: While this is true, it wouldn't necessarily apply to a `malloc`ed area of memory that had been cleared to zeros with `memset` (or alternatively, allocated and zeroed by `calloc`). That's because C doesn't guarantee that the binary representation of a null pointer is all zeros (or that the binary representation of a floating-point 0 is all zeros, but that's off topic), although exceptions are very rare.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can initialise an array of structs something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct buffer_t {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} buffer_t;

int main()
{
    int i;
    int NUM_ARRAY=4;

    buffer_t buffer[NUM_ARRAY];

    for(i=0; i<NUM_ARRAY; i++)
    {
        buffer[i].a = 0;
        buffer[i].b = 1;
        buffer[i].c = 2;
    };

    return 0;
}
```

I feel like you're after more than this though?

Comment: This is quite error-prone if fields are added or their type changes.